# checking checkboxes with name and within a div

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xhtml, checkbox

I am trying to write some javascript which will check the checkboxes within a div where the checkbox name matches the given name. Here is what I have, but it isn't doing anything:

```
function checkbox_control(container_id,element_name,status) {
    var children = document.getElementById(container_id).childNodes;
    alert(element_name);
    for(var b=0; b < children.length; b++) {
        if(children[b].name == element_name){
            children[b].checked = status;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getElementsByTagName instead of childNodes (it makes recursive search of elements). LIke this:

```
function checkbox_control(container_id,element_name,status) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementById(container_id).getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var b=0; b < checkboxes.length; b++) {
        if(checkboxes[b].name == element_name){
            checkboxes[b].checked = status;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me ([jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/brymck/gpPEg/)). Any chance it's your click event handler, using ID instead of name, asking for child nodes when they're really descendant nodes (e.g. `<div><ul><li><input type="checkbox"></li></ul></div>`), setting `status` to something aside from `"checked"`, `""`, `true` or `false`(which all work at least in Chrome)?

Answer (score 0):

Typical, you post the question, then you instantly find your own answer no matter how long you had been looking before. Changing childnodes to getElementsByTagName('input'):

```
function checkbox_control(container_id,element_name,status) {
    var children = document.getElementById(container_id).getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var b=0; b < children.length; b++) {
        if(children[b].name == element_name){
            children[b].checked = status;
        }
    }
}
```